# Apostol mathematical analysis 2nd edition definition 2.14

Tags: real-analysis

I might be totally blind but I have a question about definition 2.14 page 38 in Apostol's mathematical analysis:

Usually, to my knowledge, countable infinite requires there exists a bijective function from the set of natural numbers to the set S.

So my question is this:

why doesn't Apostol in his definition 2.14 and hence definition of countable infinite (top of page 39) write onto somewhere but only one-to-one. I mean why does he define sets to be equinumerous if there is an one-to-one between the sets and not a one-to-one from a set A onto a set B? Is this a mistake or did I indeed miss it somewhere? By this definition of equinumerous I dont think his definition of finite set (page 38 buttom) makes much sense. Because if he indeed means only one-to-one then I could claim the cardinality of the set S={1} is 5 (or any other natural number) because there exists an injective function F from S to {1,2,3,4 5} given by F(x)=x. If he required bijective then this was not possible and the cardinality is ofc 1... Also: is there a place where I can find the errata for this book? I just bought it as a supplement and I found this possible error after 5 min. I hate spending time on a simple errata and hence try to avoid it by looking at known errata. I might also just be blind. Then please point me to the place where the word onto is (not the definition on page 35 but in the definition of equinumerous or countable infinite and finite set).

Thank you for your time!

:)

Comment: Not everyone has a copy of this text on hand, and even if they did, not everyone is going to take the time and effort to go get it, look up the relevant portion, and then go out of their way to quote it and answer your question.

Comment: You did however spend time on writing this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the first edition, but I suspect that the wording of the definition is the same. If so, you overlooked an essential part of it. The definition:

> Two sets $A$ and $B$ are called equivalent, and we write $A\sim B$ if, and only if, there exists a one-to-one function $F$ whose domain is the set $A$ and whose range is the set $B$.

Requiring the range of $F$ to be $B$ means that $F$ maps $A$ **onto** $B$ and is therefore a bijection. Remember, the range of $F$ is $F[A]$, the set of images of members of $A$.

Comment: (+1) There is indeed no essential change in the second edition. The wording has changed, though, and the sentence now begins: "Two sets $A$ and $B$ are called similar, or equinumerous, and we write $\ldots$."

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: Thanks. (I should have followed my initial impulse and written ‘essentially the same’!)

Comment: Bah thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @MikkelT: No problem! You’re welcome.